# Getting this exception: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling" when I have an _id column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I keep getting this exception whenever I run my app. Not sure what's causing it. Here's some background info on this:

- I have this in my global attributes:

  ```
  public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
  ```
- And following this I have a String variable to setup my database columns:

  ```
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
              "create table sdCards (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
              + "arg0 text not null, "
              + "arg1 integer not null, "
                      + "arg2 integer not null, "
                      + "arg3 integer not null, "
                      + "arg4 integer not null, "
                      + "arg5 integer not null);";
  ```
- Finally, I create the database as such:

  ```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }
  ```

Not exactly sure what's going on. I clearly have an _id column! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.packagename/com.mydomain.packagename.MainClass}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 FROM table_name
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1741)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1757)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4002)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, sdName, writes, modifications, moved, deletes FROM sdCards
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1534)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1414)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1370)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1450)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at com.mydomain.packagename.DbAdapter.fetchAllSd(DbAdapter.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at com.mydomain.packagename.MainClass.fillData(SDBenchmark.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at com.mydomain.packagename.MainClass.onCreate(SDBenchmark.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1705)
E/AndroidRuntime(24036):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please show the code where you get this Exception and paste the LogCat-Output.

Comment: We'd need to see the code for fetchAllSd() and possibly fillData()

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting your database (may be by uninstalling your app) and then try running the app. This will recreate your database. One possibility is that you have the table already created and a select somewhere is failing because the _id column has never been created.